# mongoose doesn't abort the transaction when promise.all rejects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm trying to save several documents in a transaction and if i'm using Promise.all to run operations in parallel, and one of them fails and the promise rejects, then the other operations should rollback, but it doesn't happen
if running operations one by one, then it's working as expected

so here's the working script:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

main()
  .then(() => console.log('done'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
  },
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/transaction-test?replicaSet=myReplicaSet');

  const users = [
    {
      email: 'cred@mail.ru',
      password: '123',
    },
    {
      email: 'buba@mail.ru',
      password: '123',
    },
    {
      password: '1234',  // no 'email' property so trying to save it will result in validation error
    },
  ];

  await User.db.transaction(async session => {
    const promise1 = User.create([users[0]], { session });
    const promise2 = User.create([users[1]], { session });
    const promise3 = User.create([users[2]], { session });
    await promise1;
    await promise2;
    await promise3;
  });
};
```

the above code will work as intended and no docs will end up getting saved in the db, but if i replace the transaction part with:

```
  await User.db.transaction(async session => {
    const promise1 = User.create([users[0]], { session });
    const promise2 = User.create([users[1]], { session });
    const promise3 = User.create([users[2]], { session });
    await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]);
  });
};
```

then the first two docs will not rollback and will actually get saved to the db although the function will throw a validation error

mongoose version is 6.1.7
mongod version v5.0.4

Answer (score 1):

Try with `startTransaction` and `commitTransaction`.
Something like this:

```
const session = await mongoose.startSession();
session.startTransaction();

try {

  const promise1 = User.create([users[0]], { session });
  const promise2 = User.create([users[1]], { session });
  const promise3 = User.create([users[2]], { session });
  await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]);

  await session.commitTransaction();

} catch(error){
  // Rollback any changes made in the database
  await session.abortTransaction();

  // logging the error
  console.error(error);

  // Rethrow the error
  throw error;
} finally {
  // Ending the session
  session.endSession();
}
```

Comment: this works but you'd have implement complicated code to deal with transient transaction errors, that's why i'm trying to use mongoose's `db.transaction()` and mongodb node driver's `session.withTransaction()` helpers because they do that under the hood

Comment: I personally like this, since it helps you manage your transaction, but if you are not comfortable with this approach, you can use `Promise.allSettled()` instead of `Promise.all`. Then go over the results and if any of them has a `rejected` status, rollback the transaction.

Comment: thank you, the `Promise.allSettled()` actually works as i wanted